# Bootstrap 4 Dashboard with Django

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

Trying to set up a Bootstrap 4 Dashboard theme with Django.

If I double click any .html file in the downloaded theme folder, I get a properly displayed webpage with the graphs and everything working.

However, when I try to run the same theme through Django, I only get the text from the html file. I am quite new to Django and especially Bootstrap so not sure where to go from here.

Just to be sure all the static files are in the correct position, I have copied the whole theme folder into my static folder. I also think my settings files are configured correctely.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

Here is the partial output from the Command Prompt:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced). 
October 25, 2018 
Django version 2.1.2, using settings 'DataBooth.settings ' 
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK. 
[25/Oct/2018 "GET /dolcegusto/line HTTP/I.I" 200 9722 
[25/0ct/2018 21:29:18] "GET / static/ vendor/datatab1es/dataTab1es.bootstrap4.css HTTP/I.I" 404 1753 
Not Found: /dolcegusto/vendor/jquery/jquery . min. js 
[25/0ct/2018 21:29:18] "GET / static/ vendor/ fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css HTTP/I.I" 404 1741 
Not Found: /dolcegusto/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap. bundle. min. js 
[25/Oct/2018 "GET /static/css/sb-admin.css HTTP/I.I" 404 1672 
Not Found: /dolcegusto/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js 
[25/0ct/2018 21:29:18] "GET / static/ vendor/ bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/I.I" 404 1738 
[25/0ct/2018 21:29:18] "GET /dolcegusto/vendor/jquery/jquery . min. js HTTP/I.I" 404 2231 
[25/0ct/2018 21:29:18] "GET /dolcegusto/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/I.I" 404 2279 
Not Found: /dolcegusto/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js 
[25/0ct/2018 21:29:18] "GET /dolcegusto/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js HTTP/I.I" 404 2273 
Not Found: /d01cegusto/vendor/chart.js/Chart . min. js
```

This has been haunting me for days so hence I am turning for help to you.

Comment: Are you seeing the files when `DEBUG=True`? And have you tried the command `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes, I have run collectstatic and toggling DEBUG gives the same result with the same flat html page.

Comment: do you include the static files in your template?

Comment: I think so. I have added {% load staticfiles %} on top of the template. I also have modified path's to certain files that were in the original html..     <link href="{% static "vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Hey buddy, looking into doing the same thing (creating a dashboard UI with django) mind pointing in the direction of the theme you used ?

Comment: I have opted to pay for a theme as it offered the most flexibility and the least amount of time that I needed to spend learning and developing from any free version I have found. Here is the link if you were interested.. https://keenthemes.com/keen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this.

Basically, I needed to add the absolute path to my static folder in settings.py ..

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',]
```

After this, I only had to load static files in my html..

```
{% load static %}
```

And adding the static tag to each of the .css or js links in the template, like this..

```
<link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

So basically, my problem was that I wasn't referencing the static folder corectely.